# "I just got out of a big relationship" vs "I've just got out of a big relationship"

Tags: meaning

"I just got out of a big relationship"
"I've just got out of a big relationship"

I think that two sentences have no difference in meaning. It seems that *'ve* is omitted in the first sentence.
First, Do the native speakers usually omit the *have/has* in sentences containing the perfect tense?
Second, or am i thinking wrong? the above two sentences have any different meanings?

Answer (score 0):

the first sentence means, you left a relation in the past.
the second sentence means, you recently left a relation.
one of the usage of **present perfect** is to show an event happened recently. for example:
Have you just arrived?

Answer (score 0):

Only one of the two sentences in the question is grammatically correct.

> I just **got** out of a big relationship.

Is correct. The second should read

> I'**ve** just **gotten** out of a big relationship.

if it is to be correct.

It is not typical for "have" to be omitted in places it belongs. The simple past tense does not use "have", but it is it's own tense with its own rules.

The two sentences have basically the same meaning. Use of the present perfect ("have gotten") implies that it happened recently in the way that the simple past ("got") does not. In this case, though, the word "just" makes it explicit that it happened recently.

In any case, "big relationship" is not idiomatic English. We might call a relationship "long" or "serious" or maybe even "important", but we wouldn't say "big". So an idiomatic phrasing might be

> I just got out of a serious relationship.

Comment: This is correct from an Am.E perspective, but it may be worth noting that the got/gotten distinction you make may not be correct in a Br.E context, where 'got' is both simple past and past participle.